# Get row/cell of pointer in TreeView

Tags: gtk, gtk3

How can I find the row or cell, where my cursor resides at in a `GtkTreeView`?

I tried:

```
screen, _ := tv.Widget.GetScreen()
display, _ := screen.GetDisplay()
seat, _ := display.GetDefaultSeat()
device, _ := seat.GetPointer()
window, _ := tv.GetWindow()
_, x, y, _ := window.GetDevicePosition(device)
tx, ty := -1, -1
tv.ConvertBinWindowToTreeCoords(x, y, &tx, &ty)
_, _, row, _, rowExists := tv.GetPathAtPos(tx, ty)
```

`ConvertBinWindowToTreeCoords` converts the device position (which seems reasonable) to huge negative numbers(!?). The docs around all these position/coords are very fuzzy as to which coordinates they use exactly (and e.g. how this interacts with ScrollWindows).
Even the nomenclature between `Coords`, `Pos`, `Position` seems quite bogus to me.

Does anyone know how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be way simpler.

```
motion := gdk.EventMotionNewFromEvent(event)

x, y := motion.MotionVal()

path, _, _, _, rowExists := tv.GetPathAtPos(int(x), int(y))
if !rowExists {
    return true
}

return true
```

Using `row` was my misconception, since it actually means the indentation level.
So the real index is saved in `path`.